# move function does not work in Raku in Windows

Tags: raku, rakudo

This is my folder structure:

```
C:\USERS\SUMAN\OPENMP_CMAKE
│   shlib.pl
│   shlib.raku
│
└───resources
    └───libraries
```

the `shlib.raku` contains this line

```
move "shlib.pl", "resources/libraries"
```

When I run this script, it cannot move file. Reading the [docs here](https://docs.raku.org/routine/move), I expected it to work. Instead it throws this error:

```
Failed to move 'C:\Users\suman\openmp_cmake\shlib.pl' to 'C:\Users\suman\openmp_cmake\resources\libraries': Failed to copy file: operation not permitted
  in block <unit> at c:\Users\suman\openmp_cmake\shlib.raku line 1
```

I suppose it is system related. But is there a way to get around this? Because it will help me automate things. This is my system information:

```
Host Name:                 SUMANKHANAL
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.19043 N/A Build 19043
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          N/A
Registered Organization:   N/A
Product ID:                00331-20350-00000-AA867
Original Install Date:     2/19/2022, 1:41:50 PM
System Boot Time:          4/10/2022, 9:35:07 PM
System Manufacturer:       Dell Inc.
System Model:              Inspiron 5379
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 10 GenuineIntel ~2001 Mhz
BIOS Version:              Dell Inc. 1.17.0, 8/18/2021
Windows Directory:         C:\WINDOWS
System Directory:          C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume1
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
Time Zone:                 (UTC+05:45) Kathmandu
Total Physical Memory:     8,025 MB
Available Physical Memory: 1,442 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  14,425 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 3,820 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    10,605 MB
Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
Domain:                    WORKGROUP
Logon Server:              \\SUMANKHANAL
Hotfix(s):                 7 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                           [01]: KB5010472
                           [02]: KB5012117
                           [03]: KB5000736
                           [04]: KB5012599
                           [05]: KB5011352
                           [06]: KB5011651
                           [07]: KB5005699
Network Card(s):           2 NIC(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Qualcomm QCA61x4A 802.11ac Wireless Adapter
                                 Connection Name: Wi-Fi
                                 DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                                 DHCP Server:     192.168.1.254
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: 192.168.1.83
                                 [02]: fe80::d948:4175:e48d:b886
                                 [03]: 2400:1a00:b111:3e81:c506:663d:5c33:418a
                                 [04]: 2400:1a00:b111:3e81:d948:4175:e48d:b886
                                 [05]: 2400:1a00:b111:3e81::2
                           [02]: Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
                                 Connection Name: Bluetooth Network Connection
                                 Status:          Media disconnected
Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
                           Second Level Address Translation: Yes
                           Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

---

In [repl.it](https://replit.com/) (Linux) also, I don't see if its working, here is the error:

```
Failed to move '/home/runner/WrithingCharmingSemicolon/openmp_cmake/shlib.pl' to '/home/runner/WrithingCharmingSemicolon/openmp_cmake/resources/libraries': Failed to copy file: illegal operation on a directory
  in block <unit> at shlib.raku line 1
```

Comment: I assume the repl.it error is more about not being allowed to do file actions.  FWIW, `move` tries to copy the file, and then unlink the original.  Could you see whether the first part (the copy) or the second part (the unlink) failed.

Comment: Yes `move C:\Users\suman\openmp_cmake\shlib.pl C:\Users\suman\openmp_cmake\resources\libraries` works from command prompt. Also in python, `import shutil;
shutil.move("shlib.pl", "resources/libraries")` works within python script without knowing anything about my Windows. Why is Raku different? Is it because Rakudo binaries are not [signed with Windows certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing#Trusted-Library_Attribute) or something else? I have kept my Windows info in the question.

Comment: Is this a Windows directory issue (caveat or bug)? Does your destination directory have to be `"resources\libraries"` not `"resources/libraries"`?

Comment: No does not think so. Because `resources\libraries` throws `Unrecognized backslash sequence: '\l'` error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, `move` does not work on directories, that's what the error says if you do more or less the same in Linux

```
move "shlib.pl", IO::Path.new("resources/libraries/shlib.pl")
```

This works in Linux, can you please check if it works in Windows? It does create a path which should be independent of the filesystem conventions, thanks to using [`IO::Path`](https://docs.raku.org/type/IO::Path#routine_move)

Comment: Yes it works in Windows too. Doing only `move "shlib.pl", "resources/libraries/shlib.pl"` seems enough. But I find it quite weird though, compared to other programming languages. Because I cannot do `move ".*\.pl", "resources/libraries/"` to move multiple files matching a pattern. Instead I have to write a loop to run this line for each file.

Comment: @SumanKhanal the arguments to `move` are just files, not globs, I'm afraid...

Answer (score 5):

***You can copy multiple files from one directory to another using Raku, however (in the hope of code portability) Raku provides a mechanism that limits reliance upon your OS-provided shell.***

Which is to say: when using Raku's `copy` or `move` or `rename` commands, give these file-system commands a `dir()` parameter, indicating which-files-in-which-directory you wish to operate upon. Include a `for` statement to loop over the files (and/or directories) you've identified. Below is an example when you've navigated to the `source` directory:

Shell:

```
$ pwd
~/parent
$ cd source
~/parent/source$ ls
~/parent/source$ echo "for all persons" > persons.txt
~/parent/source$ echo "now is the time" > time.txt
~/parent/source$ ls
persons.txt time.txt
```

Raku one-liners:

```
~parent/source$ raku -e 'for dir(test => / .+ \.txt $ /) {.say};'
"persons.txt".IO
"time.txt".IO
~/parent/source$ raku -e 'mkdir IO::Path.new("../dest");'
~/parent/source$ raku -e 'for dir(test => / .+ \.txt $ /) { copy $_, "../dest/$_", createonly => True};'
~/parent/source$ ls ../dest
persons.txt time.txt
```

If you're sitting in a `parent` directory, it's a tiny bit more work to `copy` or `move` or `rename` from/to the appropriate source/destination directories:

Raku one-liners:

```
~/parent$ raku -e 'for dir("./source", test => / .+ \.txt $ /) {.say};'
"./source/persons.txt".IO
"./source/time.txt".IO
~/parent$ raku -e 'mkdir IO::Path.new("./dest2");'
~/parent$ raku -e 'for dir("./source", test => / .+ \.txt $ /) { copy $_, "./dest2/" ~ $_.basename, createonly => True};'
~/parent$ ls ./dest2
persons.txt time.txt
```

My guess is Raku instituted this design-decision to allow users to learn/remember ***one*** pattern-matching language (Raku-regexes) rather than two (Raku-regexes AND shell-globbing).

https://docs.raku.org/type/IO::Path